# How to dynamically change SLD style of WMS layer being served by GeoServer from PostGIS?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, sld

How can I dynamically change a SLD style of a WMS layer being served by GeoServer from PostGIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found an answer in http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/dynamic-SLD-with-openlayers-td3806595.html

### It solved my problem. Example:

```
  var tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS ("state","http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms", {......})

 tiled.mergeNewParams({SLD :some_sld_url });
```

If layer already had styles specified by "Styles" property, then you have to set it to null:

tiled.mergeNewParams({ SLD: some_sld_url, STYLES: null });

There is no need to redraw the layer. "mergeNewParams" will do it.

Comment: What link should I use? Should I save the SLD in a XML file and then use the path to this file? Or there is a link which can get through the geoserver platform (related to this SLD)?